# Why are three Spray.io routes being run simultaneously?

Tags: scala, spray

I have the following routes defined below in Spray.io. What's really weird is every time I call something like `/user/8dsdf974jj` it actually runs all three of the following routes. Humorously, I noticed it because I was getting 20 verification emails sent to me at the same time.

```
pathPrefix("user") {
  pathPrefix(PathElement) { id =>
        path("") {
              get { // code here }
        } ~
        path("verify" / "request") {
              get { // code here }
        } ~
        path("verify" / "confirm") {
              get { // code here }
        }
      }
}
```

Can someone explain why the path doesn't terminate the routing tree? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, the problem is that your code runs at route-building time not when the request is actually handled.

This document explain it in longer form: http://spray.io/documentation/spray-routing/advanced-topics/understanding-dsl-structure/

If you look on the mailing list you will find lots of threads about this exact problem which should help you further.

HTH

Comment: Yep just found this out myself, but hadn't put up an answer. Thanks for posting this!